# Mounting memory buffer as a file without writing to disk

Tags: c++, ipc

I have a server and needs to feed data from clients to a library; however, that library only supports reading files (it uses [open](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) to access the file).

Since the data can get pretty big, I rather not write it out to a temporary file, read it in with the library then delete it afterwards. Instead I would like to do something similar to a ramdisk where there's a file in which the content is actually in memory.

However, there can be multiple clients sending over large data, I don't think constantly calling `mount` and `umount` to create a ramdisk for each client is efficient. Is there a way for me to mount an existing memory buffer as a file without writing to disk?

- The library does not support taking in a file descriptor nor `FILE*`. It will only accept a path which it feeds directly to `open`
- I do have the library's source code and attempted to add in a function that uses `fmemopen`; however, `fmemopen` returns a `FILE*` with no file descriptor. The internals of the library works only with file descriptors and it is too complex to change/add support to use `FILE*`
- I looked at `mmap`, but it appears to be no different than writing out the data to a file
- Using `mount` requires sudo access and I prefer not to run the application as sudo

```cpp
bool IS_EXITING = false;
ssize_t getDataSize( int clientFD ) { /* ... */}

void handleClient( int clientFD ) {
  // Read in messages to get actual data size
  ssize_t dataSize = getDataSize( clientFD );

  auto* buffer = new char[ dataSize ];

  // Read in all the data from the client
  ssize_t bytesRead = 0;
  while( bytesRead < dataSize ) {
    int numRead = read( clientFD, buffer + bytesRead, dataSize - bytesRead );
    bytesRead += numRead;
    
    // Error handle if numRead is <= 0
    if ( numRead <= 0 ) { /* ... */ }
  }
  
  // Mount the buffer and get a file path... How to do this
  std::string filePath = mountBuffer( buffer );

  // Library call to read the data
  readData( filePath );

  delete[ ] buffer;
}

void runServer( int socket )
  while( !IS_EXITING ) {
    auto clientFD = accept( socket, nullptr, nullptr );
    // Error handle if clientFD <= 0
    if ( clientFD <= 0 ) { /* ... */ }

    std::thread clientThread( handleClient, clientFD );
    clientThread.detach( ); 
  }
}
```

Comment: First, the code is obviously C++, not `C`.  Only tag the languages you are actually using.  Second, `auto* buffer = new char[ dataSize ];` -- It would be better if this were `std::vector<char> buffer(dataSize);`, since depending on what happens here: `if ( numRead <= 0 ) { /* ... */ }` -- you could have a memory leak.

Comment: You could use a named pipe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `/dev/fd`. Get the file descriptor of the socket, and append that to `/dev/fd/` to get the filename.

If the data is in a memory buffer, you could create a thread that writes to a pipe. Use the file descriptor of the read end of the pipe with `/dev/fd`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Do you by chance know the lifetime of the file descriptor of the socket? If the client closes the connection, will the file descriptor still be there in /dev/fd/?

Comment: As long as you can read from the file descriptor you can read from the corresponding `/dev/fd` file. The two are equivalent.

Comment: Note: /dev/fd is a link to /proc/self/fd, which lists all the processes open filedescriptors. The filename will disappear on close but if anyone opens the file before that their file descriptor remains valid.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I think `/dev/fd` is more portable than `/proc/self/fd`, e.g. it works on MacOS as well as Linux.